# Custom button has missing text

Tags: android, custom-controls

I am trying to make a custom button, having two 9patch files, one for normal state and one for status.

First I tried with a simple 9patch background and the result is fine:

```
<Button android:id="@+id/btnTest"
        android:layout_height="80dip" 
        android:layout_width="135dip" 
        android:text="Test" 
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/imgsomeimage"
        android:background="@drawable/main_button_background">
</Button>
```

I get a button with a image and a text bellow it. Everything with the main_button_background underneath

I create a new xml file (main_menu_button.xml) with the following content

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
        android:state_focused="false"
        android:state_selected="false"
        android:state_pressed="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/main_button_background" />
    <item
        android:state_focused="false"
        android:state_selected="true"
        android:state_pressed="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/main_button_background" />

    <!-- Focused states -->
    <item
        android:state_focused="true"
        android:state_selected="false"
        android:state_pressed="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/main_button_background_pressed" />
    <item
        android:state_focused="true"
        android:state_selected="true"
        android:state_pressed="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/main_button_background_pressed" />

    <!-- Pressed -->
    <item
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/main_button_background_pressed" />
  </selector>
```

The button becomes:

```
<Button android:id="@+id/btnTest"
        android:layout_height="80dip" 
        android:layout_width="135dip" 
        android:text="Test" 
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/imgsomeimage"
        android:background="@drawable/main_menu_button">
```

Now the text isn't displayed, only the background and the imgsomeimage.
What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. The pressed background image had a different size. After resizing it as the normal background everything works fine.

Comment: My 9 patches are both the same dimensions and my text disappears when I set selected (and invoke the other state) :(.